# Flutter google_mobile_ads 2.0.1

Tags: flutter, version, google-mobile-ads

first of all hi, I can't install google_mobile_ads 2.0.1 plugin in my Flutter project and there is no content on the web about it. pub.dev site does not show step by step build. please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

On the package page goto installation copy the dependency and add to your project in pubspect.ml file under the dependency.click on add dependencies .just import it and you can use it

Comment: Could you give me your Instagram username to help me in more detail? Thank you so much.